# Git - Merging 'add' from two branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-history-graph

1. I have `Branch1` and `Branch2`, and have added a file with same name in both branches. Say `Branch1\folder\file.txt` and `Branch2\folder\file.txt`.
2. I merge `Branch1` into `Branch2` and get an expected merge conflict on the file.
3. I select `Branch1` version of the file, commit and push.

When I see history of the file in `Branch2` I see that the file is 'add'ed and instead of 'modified'. I expect modified because the file was already present in `Branch2` and was updated by the file from `Branch1` but Git history doesn't reflect this.

Is this by design? Is there any another way of achieving the same result with correct/desired history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background Information

Unlike most other version control systems, git does not track files, but instead it tracks content. Each commit is a large snapshot of the code, which means that you are guaranteed to get back exactly what you put in, bit for bit. The file data we use to organize and understand the snapshot is more like metadata inside the git model.

When you compare two commits, even if there are 30 commits between them, git only looks at the two commits you are comparing. As a result, it needs a set of rules for how to interpret the metadata when it sees content being moved around and modified.

So it seeing a file as added, deleted, moved, modified, etc, is not from it reading a log of your actions, but by comparing two snapshots and interpreting the difference.

### To Answer Your Question

This is by design because git sees the history as a comparison of two snapshots rather than a series of discreet human actions.

Here is a diagram of the scenario you described. (Arrows point from child to parent)

[image]

Comparing each pair of commits below, git will interpret file.txt as:

```
A > B : Added
A > C : Added
B > D : Modified
C > D : Unchanged
A > D : Added
```

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly complements my understanding. Is there any other way to achieve this operation, because I want to preserve the history of what happened to that file in Branch2 before it got overwritten.

Comment: There is no way to alter this behavior, but the history is preserved in commit b. If you want a more granular view of the history, you can go through the history commit by commit to see what happened if you need to. This is a fundamental feature of the git data model and is not only one of the major contributors to git's speed but the primary factor in how easy merging is in git as well.